# error from Matlab rightCam = imaq.VideoDevice('winvideo', 1, 'MJPG_640x480');

Tags: matlab

When I do this Matlab R2015a:

inf = imaqhwinfo ('winvideo')

inf =

```
   AdaptorDllName: 'C:\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2015a\osgenericvideointerfa...'
AdaptorDllVersion: '4.9 (R2015a)'
      AdaptorName: 'winvideo'
        DeviceIDs: {[1]  [2]  [3]}
       DeviceInfo: [1x3 struct]
```

vid = videoinput('winvideo',1,'MJPG_640x480')

rightCam = imaq.VideoDevice('winvideo', 1, 'MJPG_640x480');

I get this error:
"Attempt to reference field of non-structure array."

imaqhwinfo  shows my Logitech C290 stereo webcams.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do it a different way..........

There are two different ways to talk to cameras in the Image Acquisition Toolbox.  One is using a videoinput object, the other is using imaq.VideoDevice. You have to use one or the other, but not both at the same time. imaq.VideoDevice, is the simplest way.

```
leftCam = imaq.VideoDevice('winvideo', 2, 'MJPG_640x480');
rightCam = imaq.VideoDevice('winvideo', 1, 'MJPG_640x480');
leftCam.ReturnedDataType = 'uint8';
leftCam.DeviceProperties.FocusMode = 'manual';
leftCam.DeviceProperties.WhiteBalanceMode = 'manual';

rightCam.ReturnedDataType = 'uint8';
rightCam.DeviceProperties.FocusMode = 'manual';
rightCam.DeviceProperties.WhiteBalanceMode = 'manual';

%% take pictures
%player = vision.DeployableVideoPlayer;
count = 1;
for i = 1:1000
    leftImage = step(leftCam);
    rightImage = step(rightCam);
    dispImage = imfuse(leftImage, rightImage, 'montage');
    if mod(i, 20) == 0
        imwrite(leftImage, sprintf('left/image%d.png', count));
        imwrite(rightImage, sprintf('right/image%d.png', count));
        dispImage = zeros(size(dispImage), 'like', dispImage);
        count = count+1;
    end
    imshow(dispImage);
    drawnow;
end
```